# IcCube, How to change legend labels in an AMChart widget?

Tags: amcharts, iccube-reporting

How can I change the legend labels in an AMCharts widget ?
I know I can change Category axis labels using their labelFunction(),
Is there a way to do the same with legend ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this function in the JS `On data received` event did the trick!

```
function(context, data, $box) {

    data.underlying.axes[0].caption[0] = textPreviousYear;
    data.underlying.axes[0].caption[2] = textPeriod;

    return data;
}
```

Not sure it is the best way to proceed, but it works.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but it should work without any side effects